# Objectify sequence query

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I try to have such code:

```
    Query<Card> query = ofy().load().type(Card.class);

    UserData creator = ofy().load().type(UserData.class).id(creatorId).now();
    if (creator != null && UserType.USER.equals(creator.getUserType())) {
        query.filter("creator", creator);
    }
    if (orderColumnName != null) {
        query.order((ascending ? "" : "-") + orderColumnName);
    }
    query.offset(startRow).limit(limit);
    return query.list();
```

But it doesn't filter.
Also this filter:

```
    UserData creator = ofy().load().type(UserData.class).id(creatorId).now();
    Query<Card> query = ofy().load().type(Card.class).filter("creator", creator);
```

Any idea why?

**EDITED**

My class Card.java

```
@Entity
public class Card implements PersistableObject {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @Index
    Date createDate;

    ...

    @Index
    Ref<UserData> creator;

    ...

    public UserData getCreator() {
        if (creator != null) {
            return creator.get();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setCreator(UserData creator) {
        this.creator = Ref.create(creator);
    }
}
```

My class UserData.java

```
@Entity
public class UserData implements PersistableObject {

    @Id
    Long id;

    Ref<EaistoAccount> eaistoAccount;

    UserType userType;

    public EaistoAccount getEaistoAccount() {
        if (eaistoAccount == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return eaistoAccount.get();
    }

    public void setEaistoAccount(EaistoAccount aistoAccount) {
        this.eaistoAccount = Ref.create(aistoAccount);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work means that I expect to get filtered entities to corresponding UserData but it doesn't filter when I split query in a few parts also it filters when I use query in one line.

Comment: What does _"doesn't work"_ mean? Do you get an error message? Does the program produce an output that differs from the expected one?

Comment: I mean that filtering doesn't work in first case but works in second.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Can you show your `Card` and `UserData` classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution:

> Why aren't my queries working properly? All of Objectify's
>   intermediate command objects are immutable. This will not work:
>
> Query q = ofy().load().type(Foo.class); q.filter("bar", bar);
>   List foos = q.list(); The filter command did nothing because you
>   did not reassign q. You need this:
>
> q = q.filter("bar", bar); Alternatively, chain the whole sequence in a
>   single statement. Read more here.

https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions